# Executing SSIS packages from the SSIS catalog on SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2012

With the new SSIS catalog of SQL Server 2012, the previous way of executing SSIS packages from an SQL Server via C# *locally* (it basically downloads the package and executes it on the callers machine) does no longer work:

```
Application app = new Application();
Package pkg = app.LoadFromSqlServer("\\FolderRoot", "myserver", null, null, null);
pkg.Execute();
```

This approach is discussed in the MSDN article [Loading and Running a Local Package Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx).

For SQL Server 2012, using the SSIS catalog approach, it seems the new way of executing SSIS packages is by using the classes in the [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.aspx) namespace. Much to my confusion, Microsoft doesn't provide any useful documentation for this new way to handle package execution. The [following blog post](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2013/01/call-ssis-2012-package-within-net.html) suggests the following way to do it:

```
SqlConnection ssisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
IntegrationServices ssisServer = new IntegrationServices(ssisConnection);
PackageInfo ssisPackage = ssisServer.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders["MasterChild"].Projects["MasterChildPackages"].Packages["master.dtsx"];
long executionIdentifier = ssisPackage.Execute(false, null, executionParameter);
```

However, this does not execute locally, it runs on the server. My question is, with the SSIS catalog on a remote SQL Server 2012, is it still possible to execute packages locally on my own machine from that remote server?

Comment: I have never tried executing a package from the SSISDB programmatically. However, a package in the SSIDB is not just a single stand-alone package. It is part of a project. The package has to be executed in the context of the project which can only be done through the SSIDB.

Comment: That's true, the package needs to execute in the context of it's project. Therefore, the real question is how do I execute an entire remotely deployed project locally on my PC?

Comment: using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime; have you tried this namespace..you want to execute this in c# code right?

Comment: @Govind Yes I want to execute it in C#. That namespace does not work for SQL server where the packages are stored in the SSIS catalog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Define "does not work"**. As I can see from the documentation, the same code you gave(the one that works for < 2012) SHOULD still work with 2012, it is not marked as deprecated, or anything like that.

Make sure you reference this dll, instead of old one:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll*

//edit; it seems that you are indeed right for now: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141708.aspx

Perhaps this will get you going(ps I have no idea if this will work, but I saw some useful methods, and perhaps you can get it working):

```
var projectBytes = ssisServer.Catalogs["SSISDB"]
                             .Folders["MasterChild"]
                             .Projects["MasterChildPackages"].GetProjectBytes();

// note that projectBytes is basically __URFILE__.ispac      
using (var existingProject = Project.OpenProject(new MemoryStream(projectBytes)))
{
    existingProject.PackageItems["master.dtsx"].Package.Execute(.... todo ....)
}
```

Comment: The code you've provided executes the project on the server. This is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Try the same code, but save projectBytes as yourFIle.ispac, and try executing dtexec /Project yourFIle.ispac /package master.dtsx. If that does execute locally, I would try and use APIMONITOR to see what methods it's calling. If that does not execute locally, I don't think SSIS packages can be executed locally, though I did not find any "proof" nor counter-proof for this.

Comment: Actually, your code looks like it could be what I need. I'm currently testing this out!

Comment: This absolutely runs the project locally. Thank you very much!